# How do you find the area of Circle?

Tags: geometry

I'm taking Geometry, and I'm a Sophomore in High School. For my math work, I'm looking for the Area of a Circle. I know the general equation is $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$, but I am struggling on how to find the EXACT area. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying really. What do you mean by EXACT area? Isn't it $\pi r^2$? And in case you thought THAT was an approximation, $\pi$ is derived from the formula, not the reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "general equation" you give, $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$, defines (the boundary of) a circle with center having coordinates $(h,k)$ and radius $r$.

Thus the area of the circle comes from the familiar formula $A=\pi r^2$, where this $r$ is the same as the $r$ in the general equation.

Comment: Note your parenthetic remark is wrong, or at least misleading. The equation in question defines the circle. If one wnts to refer to that with its interior it's a disk.

Comment: For this level of question I don't think it's useful to assume that everyone is working with standard terminology, but the addendum is appreciated.

Comment: Eric: I see what you mean, those new to geometric terms might think a circle contained its inside as well as boundary, and then your parenthetic remark is useful for them.